# ORACLE BPEL Adding whitespace after newlines

Tags: java, regex, oracle

As part of a larger task we need to extract information from fixed field length text files. The data files were original developed for EDI but are in widespread use through the industry so we can't ask for a more modern way of encoding data.

I wrote a Java program, implemented as a user defined function, to do the file parsing. It works properly when run locally within jDeveloper. One of the things it does is remove all the newline characters so I can count record lengths accurately. When I try to run it from a simple composite application on the SOA server I find a strange problem: the newlines are gone but I get a new whitespace character in their place.

I do not know what can cause this or how to reliably deal with it. My composite is very simple; I just paste the file content into the "input" field using the test console on the SOA server and this sends the string to the user defined function which parses the file and outputs an XML fragment I can then read.

If I manually strip all the newlines and paste that in, all is well and it works fine but if I send a the data with newlines I get extra whitespace.

Is the composite trying to normalize newlines for me? If so; I would like to know how to make it quit.

Comment: `I wrote a Java program` Can you show us that?

Comment: I figured this out (sort of) ... it is the test interface (the ADF console application) that is part of the SOA deployment that was adding the white space.

I tried running the composite from SOAP UI and I'm not having the problem.

Thanks for responding Prateek.

I can't share the Java source because it has proprietary credit bureau information embedded.